# Running multiple Bitcoin nodes on same network

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I want to run a **bitcoin node two separate devices** (computer + dedicated hardware device) **on the same network** (and would like them to be externally accessible).

I've read it is critical that you forward port 8333 on your router to the IP address of the computer that is running your node, so I'm not sure what to do on the dedicated hardware device then.

I've seen you can add `port` and `rpcport` arguments to the bitcoin.conf file, but I'm can't figure out exactly how this setup will work on the same network with two different bitcoin nodes.

Any help by someone more expert (most people likely ha) than me would be appreciated, thanks!

`Bitcoin.conf` file

```
daemon=1
server=1
prune=750
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
```

Comment: If you can post your configuration file, that will be great.

Comment: @tim sure! Updated my question with the conf file info.  Today I tried adding `rpcport=8332` to it, but realized I didn't really know what I was doing there to have clarity, so I decided to ask a question.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming. You may be able to get help on our sister site [bitcoin.se].

Comment: @MichaelHampton hey my bad! thanks for the heads up, I will post over there instead. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that you have to forward port 8333. Bitcoin works just as fine without your node being externally accessible. If you want a connection between both of your local two nodes, just use the "addnode" flag with their LAN address.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like the nodes to be externally accessible (be able to take inbound is what I'm talking about), in which case does that change anything about your answer? And I don't want a connection between both of my two local nodes, sorry if that part wasn't clear.

Comment: You will have to run one of the nodes on a different p2p port than 8333. This is perfectly fine, since getaddr will advertise your ip address anlong with the port.

One thing you should to is either use UPNP or specify the external address using the "bind" option and take care of the NAT tables in your router yourself. Otherwise the node will only know its local LAN address, flag it as "not accessible" and not broadcast your address at all; that would mean that even if your node is externally accessible, nobody would access it!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation!  I will give it a try!